# Specification using fields with underscore

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So, I am trying to do a dynamic filter search, using Specifications on my JPA connection.

I want to send something like this in my request:

`xxxxxxxx.com/stuff?limit=10&offset=0&some_field_with_underscore=zzz`

In my database, the field is: `some_field_with_underscore`

In my entity I have it like this:

```
@Column(name = "some_field_with_underscore", nullable = false)
    private String someFieldWithUnderscore;
```

Using the findAll() without filters is ok and no problem with that but, when I try to use the Specification with `"some_field_with_underscore"` it fails and a error is thrown.

So, my question is, how can I use fields with underscores this way? (In this case, I can't use `someFieldWithUnderscore` in my request but I know that it will work)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You have to change from snake_case to camelCase. Here you'll find some ideas https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-camel-case

Comment: You are mixing database model (via api) with java model. In that case you have to translate database model via api-> java.